# Any poisons that mimic Syphilis?

Tags: medieval, chemistry, diseases, medical, poisons

In my tabletop RPG story the wife of a rich noble killed her husband.

Her story is that he cheated on her and when she told him that she knew, he tried to kill her and she only defended herself. During the burial preparations decomposed bones were found as if the victim was in a late stage of syphilis.

Magic is banned in this kingdom and any suspicious activity is quickly dealt with by the Holy Inquisition.

Is there be a real world poison that decomposes bones in a similar way to syphilis? (This might be administered over a long period of time)

Answer (score 2):

There'd very probably be multiple other symptoms of syphilis that would be observed long before anyone got the chance to get to the skeleton. The other thing about the infection is that the symptoms can imitate a number of other conditions, so one can't merely look at the effects on the bones and be certain just based on that that the victim has syphilis.

Comment: http://www.southernnevadahealthdistrict.org/syphilis/stages-symptoms.php